# Istio ingress gateway on wsl2 docker desktop

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, istio, wsl-2, istio-gateway

I am trying to run the bookinfo example on my local with wsl2 and docker desk. I am having issues when trying to access the productpage service via the gateway as I got the connection refused. I am not sure whether I missed anything. Here is what I have done after googled a lot on the internet

1. Deployed all services from bookinfo example and all up running, I can curl productpage from other service using kubectl exec
2. Deployed bookinfo-gateway using the file from the example without any change under the default namespace

```
Name:         bookinfo-gateway
Namespace:    default
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  <none>
API Version:  networking.istio.io/v1beta1
Kind:         Gateway
Metadata:
  Creation Timestamp:  2021-06-06T20:47:18Z
  Generation:          1
  Managed Fields:
    API Version:  networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
    Fields Type:  FieldsV1
    fieldsV1:
      f:metadata:
        f:annotations:
          .:
          f:kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration:
      f:spec:
        .:
        f:selector:
          .:
          f:istio:
        f:servers:
    Manager:         kubectl-client-side-apply
    Operation:       Update
    Time:            2021-06-06T20:47:18Z
  Resource Version:  2053564
  Self Link:         /apis/networking.istio.io/v1beta1/namespaces/default/gateways/bookinfo-gateway
  UID:               aa390a1d-2e34-4599-a1ec-50ad7aa9bdc6
Spec:
  Selector:
    Istio:  ingressgateway
  Servers:
    Hosts:
      *
    Port:
      Name:      http
      Number:    80
      Protocol:  HTTP
Events:          <none>
```

3. The istio-ingressgateway can expose to the outside via localhost (not sure how this can be configured as it is deployed during istio installation) on 80, which I as understand will be used by bookinfo-gateway
   kubectl get svc istio-ingressgateway -n istio-system
   [image]
4. following Determining the ingress IP and ports section in [the instruction](https://istio.io/latest/docs/setup/getting-started/).

My  INGRESS_HOST=127.0.0.1 and INGRESS_PORT is 80

5. curl -v -s http://127.0.0.1:80/productpage | grep -o ".*"

```
*   Trying 127.0.0.1:80...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* connect to 127.0.0.1 port 80 failed: Connection refused
* Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 80: Connection refused
* Closing connection 0
```

6. trying this http://127.0.0.1/productpage on browser, return 404. Does this 404 mean the gateway is kind of up but virtual service is not working??
7. further question if it is relevant. I am a bit confusing how wsl2 works now. It looks like localhost on windows browser and wsl2 terminal are not the same thing, though I know there is kind of forwarding from windows to wsl2 server (which I can get its IP from /etc/resolv.conf). if it is the same, why one return connection refused and the other return 404
8. On windows I have tried to disable IIS or anything running on port 80 (net stop http). Somehow, I still can see something listen to port 80

```
netstat -aon | findstr :80
  TCP    0.0.0.0:80             0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       4


tasklist /svc /FI "PID eq 4"

Image Name                     PID Services
========================= ======== ============================================
System                           4 N/A
```

I am wondering whether this is what causes the difference in point 7? As windows is running on another http server on port 80?

I know this a lot of questions asked. I believe many of us that new to istio and wsl2 may have similar questions. Hopefully, this helps others as well. Please advise.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to get this working: This is what I did.
Shell into the distro (mine was Ubuntu 20.04 LTS)

Run:

```
    sudo apt-get -y install socat
    sudo apt update
    sudo apt upgrade
    exit
```

The above will add socat (which I was getting errors with when looking at the istio logs - connection refused) and update the distro to the latest updates (and upgrade them)

Now you have to run a port-forward to be able to host localhost: to hit the istio gateway with:

```
    kubectl port-forward svc/istio-ingressgateway 8080:80 -n istio-system
```

If you are already using 8080, just remove it from the command, just use :80 and the port forward will select a free port.

Now go to

```
    http://localhost:8080/productpage
```

You should hit the page and the port-forward should output

```
    Handling connection for 8080
```

Hope that helps...
Good thing is now I don't have to use Hyper-V or another cluster installer like minikube/microk8s and use the built-in kubernetes in docker desktop and... my laptop doesn't seem under load for what I'm doing too.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a problem with WSL2 itself, probably connected with [Local sites running in WSL2 not accessible in browser #5298](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/5298).

You can work around that by issuing

```
ip addr show
```

in your WSL distro, and replacing `127.0.0.1`/`localhost` with `eth0` address. In my case it is `172.21.29.254` - so URL is http://172.21.29.254/productpage

This workaround worked for me.

Comment: thanks. as suggested
    inet 172.18.98.178/28 brd 172.18.98.191 scope global eth0

Instead of connection refused I got this instead

curl http://172.18.98.191/productpage
*   Trying 172.18.98.191:80...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Immediate connect fail for 172.18.98.191: Network is unreachable
* Closing connection 0
curl: (7) Couldn't connect to server

Comment: Try `172.18.98.178`

Comment: 172.18.98.178 return connection refused

Comment: I skipped one step in my answer that may be important: I shutdown WSL with `wsl --shutdown` and then restarted it through Docker Desktop. It's one of the workarounds in the GitHub issue I mentioned. Additionaly, if possible, add `C:\Windows\System32\wsl.exe` to Windows Defender Firewall.